# DataStage error - Oracle ORA-03135 connection lost contact

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, etl, datastage, information-server

In DataStage 9.1.2 I am getting this message error when I try to extract some data within a Oracle Connector

```
ORA_MONTO: The OCI function OCISessionEnd returned status -1. Error code: 3,135, Error message: ORA-03135: connection lost contact
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 901 Serial number: 13587.
```

It is into a parallel job that merge data from 6 differents sources (Oracle queries) and write it into a dataset file.

I tried to add more nodes but in log I see this:

> ORACLE_CONNECTOR: The connector will run in sequential mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to ask for parallel read permissions to the DBA and then I could run my job in parallel mode (including access to database)

```
grant select on sys.dba_extents to [user];
```